# Struts 2 - JQuery plugin: Spinner Value change event

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

```jsp
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

I have used a spinner like this code below:

```jsp
<sj:spinner id="SpinnerQ" onchange="" mouseWheel="true" value="%{Quantiy}" readonly="true"  max="30" min="1" >
```

I want to get the value when I click button up or down of spinner and show that value on message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below to *get the value when you click button up or down of spinner and show that value on message box*.

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.subscribe("changeTopic", function(event,data) {
     alert($("#spinner2").val());
 });
</script>
<sj:spinner
    label="Select a Number"
          name="spinner2"
          id="spinner2"
          onChangeTopics="changeTopic"
          min="5"
          max="50"
          step="2"
          value="25"/>
```